# Controller action that changes a param, reloads the model, and rerenders?

Tags: ember.js

Say I have the following route:

```
this.resource('storyBox', {
  path: "story_box/:category_id/:page"
})
```

In my route:

```
App.StoryBoxRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Story.find({"sid": parseInt(params.category_id), page: parseInt(params.page), count: 8})
  })
```

So, this works great if I access via URL a valid resource:

`http://myserver/#/story_box/<validID>/<page`

But I can't figure out for the life of me how to generate linkTo helpers that will allow accessing the next/pervious page, as the linkTo helper expects a model. Am I supposed to just build up the URLs as a property? That seems like an ugly hack.

Comment: Any luck with this one? I'm facing the same problem with my current project.

Comment: Nope. I ended up giving up on Ember as a useable technology.

Comment: Ok, I ended up solving it via an action that translated it to the proper route but I'm not really that fond about it.